# How can I split a Dictionary into multiple dictionaries based on groups of key values?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, split

I have a dictionary `Dictionary<string, string>` which holds a set of KeyValuePairs KVPs.
These are stored in dictionary for purposes of this illustration `_test`
These are intending to be used for SQL INSERT using `command.Parameters.AddWithValue(value.key, value.Value)`
However this would insert all values into one row into SQL, where the intended outcome is multiple rows.
Example source in `_test`;

```
[0] {[Data, ONCE,UPON,A,TIME,UP,AN,ENORMOUS,GREEN,BEANSTALK,IN,THE,CLOUDS]}
[1] {[Ident, 123456789]}
[2] {[Time1, 2020-01-01T13:56:56.123]}
[3] {[Time2, 2020-01-01T13:58:02.356]}
[4] {[D, 57]}
[5] {[D1, 508,967,123,456,234,456,232,124,167,198,985,786]}
[6] {[AC, 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,3,3,1,1]}
```

I would like these values to be split into multiple dictionaries based on the grouping of values as they appear under key AC, so output would be;
I can then use `foreach` to interate each dictionary to carry out each insert.

**dict-1**
 (Contains the first 4 values based on AC being 1)

```
dictionary<string,string>

[0] {[Data, ONCE,UPON,A,TIME]}
[1] {[Ident, 123456789]}
[2] {[Time1, 2020-01-01T13:56:56.123]}
[3] {[Time2, 2020-01-01T13:58:02.356]}
[4] {[D, 57]}
[5] {[D1, 508,967,123,456]}
[6] {[AC, 1,1,1,1]}
```

**dict-2**
 (Contains next 3 values based on AC values being 2)

```
dictionary<string,string>

[0] {[Data, UP,AN,ENORMOUS]}
[1] {[Ident, 123456789]}
[2] {[Time1, 2020-01-01T13:56:56.123]}
[3] {[Time2, 2020-01-01T13:58:02.356]}
[4] {[D, 57]}
[5] {[D1, 234,456,232]}
[6] {[AC, 2,2,2]}
```

**dict-3**
 (Contains single values based on AC 4)

```
dictionary<string,string>

[0] {[Data, GREEN]}
[1] {[Ident, 123456789]}
[2] {[Time1, 2020-01-01T13:56:56.123]}
[3] {[Time2, 2020-01-01T13:58:02.356]}
[4] {[D, 57]}
[5] {[D1, 124]}
[6] {[AC, 4]}
```

**dict-4**

```
dictionary<string,string>

[0] {[Data, BEANSTALK,IN]}
[1] {[Ident, 123456789]}
[2] {[Time1, 2020-01-01T13:56:56.123]}
[3] {[Time2, 2020-01-01T13:58:02.356]}
[4] {[D, 57]}
[5] {[D1, 167,198]}
[6] {[AC, 3,3]}
```

**dict-5**

```
dictionary<string,string>

[0] {[Data, THE,CLOUDS]}
[1] {[Ident, 123456789]}
[2] {[Time1, 2020-01-01T13:56:56.123]}
[3] {[Time2, 2020-01-01T13:58:02.356]}
[4] {[D, 57]}
[5] {[D1, 985,786]}
[6] {[AC, 1,1]}
```

Is their a nice way of doing this using Linq method or Query syntax?

Comment: Did you try anything? Please show us effort of trying something, otherwise it looks like you giving us requirements for your task.

Comment: _These are intending to be used for SQL INSERT using_ - don't know about context of your application, but I hope there are better ways of inserting data into database then manually building SQL query with all parameters being of type `VARCHAR`. Are all columns in the table of type `VARCHAR`?

Comment: can you explain how is your initial dictionary initialized?
`var _test = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Data", "ONCE,UPON,A,TIME,UP,AN,ENORMOUS,GREEN,BEANSTALK,IN,THE,CLOUDS"},
    { "Ident", "123456789"},
    { "Time1", "2020-01-01T13:56:56.123"}
    { "Time2", "2020-01-01T13:58:02.356"}
    { "D", "57"}
    { "D1", "508,967,123,456,234,456,232,124,167,198,985,786"}
    { "AC", "1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,3,3,1,1"}
};
`

Comment: @Fabio

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
[Data] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Ident] [int] NULL,
[Time1] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[Time2] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[D] [int] NULL,
[D1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[AC] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: @Ivan Khorin  public static Dictionary<string, string> _test = new Dictionary<string, string>();  
Then using stringbuilder to build a list of columns and parameters to build up the sql insert statement  
INSERT INTO test (xxx,xxx) VALUES (@xxx, @xxxx)  values are added by using foreach loop on _test dictionary pulling Key and Value and then using sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(v.Key, v.Value)  
values are added to dictionary by using _test.Add(xxxxxx)

Comment: @DanGuzman says [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @DanGuzman - Great article - good read. I will look into changing away from using AddWithValue although im still left with my initial query around ways to best accomplish splitting the data into groups based on the AC values changing - many thanks

Comment: From where you get this values, can you separate values into records early?

Comment: @Fabio - they are extracted via API into a List<T> and then taken from their in one batch. I could possibly look at taking them from the list using foreach tracking the AC value changing using nested 'if ac != latest_ac' then treat that as new row or changed AC value add to new dictionary for insert and then under else treat that as same ac value so add to same sql insert

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var _test = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Data", "ONCE,UPON,A,TIME,UP,AN,ENORMOUS,GREEN,BEANSTALK,IN,THE,CLOUDS"},
    { "Ident", "123456789"},
    { "Time1", "2020-01-01T13:56:56.123"},
    { "Time2", "2020-01-01T13:58:02.356"},
    { "D", "57"},
    { "D1", "508,967,123,456,234,456,232,124,167,198,985,786"},
    { "AC", "1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,3,3,1,1"},
};

var testWithLists = _test
    .ToDictionary(
        x => x.Key,
        y => y.Value.Split(',').ToList()
    );

var prevAC = string.Empty;
var result = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

var resultPart = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < testWithLists["AC"].Count; i++)
{
    var curAC = testWithLists["AC"][i];

    if ((curAC != prevAC && i != 0) || i == (testWithLists["AC"].Count - 1))
        result.Add(resultPart.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => string.Join(',', y.Value)));

    if (curAC != prevAC)
    {
        resultPart = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            { "Data", new List<string>() },
            { "Ident", testWithLists["Ident"] },
            { "Time1", testWithLists["Time1"] },
            { "Time2", testWithLists["Time2"] },
            { "D", testWithLists["D"] },
            { "D1", new List<string>() },
            { "AC", new List<string>() },
        };
    }

    resultPart["Data"].Add(testWithLists["Data"][i]);
    resultPart["D1"].Add(testWithLists["D1"][i]);
    resultPart["AC"].Add(testWithLists["AC"][i]);   

    prevAC = curAC;
}
```

There are no checks for data, d1, ac length equality, but it works like you expect. `result` variable is a list of 5 dictionaries.

P.S. New C# 9.0 `record` type could be useful here.

P.S.P.S. Sorry that solution is not ideal :)

Comment: Initial checks the above solution works fine. I had to make one change on the `string.Join(','` and change it from char to string with double quotes around the comma due to compile error but after change all good. I will look over further tomorrow but wish to pass my thanks to all those that have contributed and additional thanks to you Ivan for the above solution

Comment: I use .NET 5.0 so maybe your version of .NET don't have Join() overload with char as parameter. Hope you can use my code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using some extension methods I already had for working with `IEnumerable`s, including a group by operator for runs, an APL Scan operator, and some basic utility methods seen here:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // returns IEnumerables of runs
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Runs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) {
        var cmp = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        using (var itemsEnum = items.GetEnumerator()) {
            bool notAtEnd;

            IEnumerable<T> NextRun() {
                T curItem;
                do {
                    curItem = itemsEnum.Current;
                    yield return curItem;
                    notAtEnd = itemsEnum.MoveNext();
                } while (notAtEnd && cmp.Equals(itemsEnum.Current, curItem));
            }

            notAtEnd = itemsEnum.MoveNext();
            while (notAtEnd)
                yield return NextRun().ToList();
        }
    }

    // APL Scan operator (like Aggregate, but returns intermediate results)
    // T combineFn(T PrevResult, T CurItem)
    // First PrevResult = items.First()
    // First CurItem = items.Skip(1).First()
    // output is items.First(), combineFn(PrevResult, CurItem), ...
    public static IEnumerable<T> Scan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, T, T> combineFn) {
        using (var itemsEnum = items.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (itemsEnum.MoveNext()) {
                T prevResult = itemsEnum.Current;

                for (; ; ) {
                    yield return prevResult;
                    if (!itemsEnum.MoveNext())
                        yield break;
                    prevResult = combineFn(prevResult, itemsEnum.Current);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // prepend a sequence with a single element
    public static IEnumerable<T> FollowedBy<T>(this T first, IEnumerable<T> rest) => first.AsSingleton().Concat(rest);
    // Join strings together with a separator
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> s, string sep) => String.Join(sep, s);

    // convert an element into a single element IEnumerable
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T item) => new[] { item };
}
```

You can create a sequence of the start positions of each combined value you want to split, then create a sequence of ranges representing the values to collect for each splittable key value.

I used a variable to specify the splittable key names in case they might change in the future, and just copied all the non-splittable key name/value pairs across.

```
var splitKeyNames = new[] { "Data", "D1", "AC" };
var splitValues = splitKeyNames.ToDictionary(n => n, n => _test[n].Split(','));

var starts = splitValues["AC"].Runs()
                .Select(run => run.Count())
                .Scan((acc, runCt) => acc + runCt);
var ranges = 0.FollowedBy(starts).Zip(starts, (start, end) => start .. end);

var ans = ranges.Select(range => _test.Keys.Where(key => !splitKeyNames.Contains(key))
                                           .Select(key => new { key, value = _test[key] })
                                           .Concat(
                                                splitKeyNames.Select(key => new {
                                                                                key,
                                                                                value = splitValues[key][range].Join(",")
                                                                            }))
                                           .ToDictionary(kv => kv.key, kv => kv.value)
                );
```